# Best practice to display pictures on mobile app that were received from server

Tags: android, performance, url

I have a server that communicates with my android app. 
In a certain tab of the app it asks for pictures from the server.
The server sends in return all the URLs for the pictures, and the app displays the pictures in the same page.

A problems accures if I have too many pictures, then the app crashes.

I have one solution in mind - to keep two versions for every picture, one with high resolution (Full HD) and another with very low resolution just for preview.

When the app asks for all the pictures, the server will send the URLs for low resolution pics and only if user askes to enlarge a picture then the app will ask the server for the high resolution pics. 
What do you think of this solution?

could you reccomend a best practice for this sort of things?

Comment: http://square.github.io/picasso/

I use the library ! The best library for image manipulations for me so far. Very simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a specialized library. They'll handle the complexity behind dealing with remotely loaded images (download, show only when loaded, caching, resizing, etc.).

These come to my mind, investigate and choose the one you like better, but there are others

- http://square.github.io/picasso/
- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader